# URL truncated after ampersand when passed thru curl in PHP (linux) using POST method

Tags: php, linux, curl, https

PHP code:

```
$fields_string = "";
foreach ($postingfields as $key=>$value) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}

$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string,'&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$client_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$response = curl_getinfo( $ch );

curl_close($ch);
```

`$client_url` php variable holds the value: `https://pcloudtest.com/Default.aspx?cid=99938`
`$fields_string` php variable holds the value: `&sid=30&title=Mr&firstname=Charles&surname=Smith`

The destination server has been set up to respond with the following HTML:

When I debug (send info to a separate txt file in linux) the value of $result is:

```
<URL>https://pcloudtest.com/Default.aspx?cid=99938</URL>
```

ie this is what the destination server is claiming has been sent to them from my end.

In other words, the $client_url is all that is being posted, and not the rest of it (ie the $fields_string) and the full URL that should've been posted should read:

```
https://pcloudtest.com/Default.aspx?cid=99938&sid=30&title=Mr&firstname=Charles&surname=Smith
```

I have tried everything I can to figure out why the php curl functions are apparently sending out a shortened URL, ie up to the first occurrence of an ampersand.  The code logic I have above has not changed in months and is working for other destination servers.
I might add that the other destination servers where this logic has no issues are http: sites not https:.  But I have been reassured by the tech guys on the other end that it definitely has nothing to do with posting to a https site.

Please help.  I hope I have outlined my issue clearly enough, and if not, please advise as to more info I can provide.

Comment: I think you are confused between `GET` and `POST`

Comment: That foreach loop is pointless. curl will happily accept an array of key:value pairs and do all the work of converting the array in a proper query string. And when doing a POST, the query parameters go into the BODY of the request, not the URL.

Comment: Actually I am not at all confused.  I know the difference, and this code is written with the intention to execute curl using POST rather than GET.
As to the foreach loop, useless or not, it has worked in the past, and still does.  I wasnt asking if the code I've presented is the most efficient or not.
I'd appreciate some constructive comments please, rather than comments that do not lead to a probable solution.